# Selenium with Python: Using a loop in read text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to pass the i parameter into the xpath expression, however it seems the syntax is not correct.

```
i = 1

while i < 9:
   
   day1Temp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='wob_dp']/div[", i, "]/div[3]/div[1]/span[1]")
   
print(day1Temp.text)
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong here?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have initialized

```
i = 1
```

Hence *`i`* is of type ***int***

Where as within the xpath you need to pass *`i`* as a *string*. So you have to convert the type of **i** as ***string***.

---

### Solution

Using [`f-strings`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) your effective code block will be:

```
i = 1
while i < 9:
   day1Temp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[@id='wob_dp']/div[{str(i)}]/div[3]/div[1]/span[1]")
   
print(day1Temp.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

to parse `i`, you can use `f-string` like below:

```
i = 1

while i < 9:
    day1Temp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[@id='wob_dp']/div[{i}]/div[3]/div[1]/span[1]")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can fix your code. Also don't forget to increment `i`

```
i = 1

while i < 9:   
   day1Temp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='wob_dp']/div[%d]/div[3]/div[1]/span[1]" % i)  
   print(day1Temp.text)
   i += 1
```